# Pushing new combined array to PHP array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, datatable

I have the following code. This fetches fields from an SQL table ("db") and prepares them for use in a datatable ("dt").

```
$columns = array(
  array( 'db' => 'Author', 'dt' => 'authors'),
  array( 'db' => 'Editor', 'dt' => 'editor')
);
```

It prints this

```
[{"authors":"John Smith; Paul Phillips","editors":"Robert Fox"},...]
```

Now I would like to push a third array (`people`) to `columns`, one that combines the previous two arrays, but without replacing them, like

```
[{"authors":"John Smith; Paul Phillips","editors":"Robert Fox","people": "John Smith: Paul Phillips; Robert Fox"},...]
```

Comment: Show what you want the final array to look

Comment: I want it to have the db values from 'Author' and 'Editor'.

Comment: I said _show_, not _describe_.  Please edit your question to include the desired result/output.

Comment: Ok, please check my edit.

Comment: The PHP code that you have at the top of your question would _not_ produce that JSON (not by itself, anyway).  It's hard to help when we can't see what's actually going on.  Remember, we have absolutely no idea what you are currently doing, or are trying to do.

Comment: I understand, and I hope I can explain it. It is followed by `$sql_details` and an `echo json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

If its just an array that you try to add to $columns,
Use *array_merge()*

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'Author', 'dt' => 'authors'),
    array( 'db' => 'Editor', 'dt' => 'editor')
);
$person = array( 'db' => 'Person', 'dt' => 'person');

$newArray = array_merge($columns, $person);
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["db"]=>
    string(6) "Author"
    ["dt"]=>
    string(7) "authors"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["db"]=>
    string(6) "Editor"
    ["dt"]=>
    string(6) "editor"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["db"]=>
    string(6) "Person"
    ["dt"]=>
    string(6) "person"
  }
}
```